# Computed column is not allowed to be used in another computed-column definition - how can I allow it?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add three new columns to my table - Scanned, Actions, and HowToFix.

However, I am getting an error that says:

> "Computed column 'Scanned' in table 'TEST_concat' is not allowed to
>   be used in another computed-column definition."

What can I do about this? I need to use the 'Scanned' computed-column for my other two columns.

Below is my code. Thank you in advance!

```
    SELECT TOP (4000) [filer_id]
      ,[filerName]
      ,[ResouceName]
      ,[UniqueIdentity]
      ,[DirID]
      ,[DirsCount]
      ,[PermCount]
      ,[RowID]
      ,[ResourceType]
      ,[ResourceFlags]
      ,[Hresult]
      ,[Details]
      ,[fsid]
      ,[Protocol]
      ,[vExport]
      ,[filerType]
      ,[Error Messages]

  FROM [master].[dbo].[TEST_concat]

ALTER TABLE
    dbo.TEST_concat
ADD
    [Scanned] AS

    CASE WHEN [DirID] > 0 AND [DirsCount] is NULL THEN 'in Shares table, but not SortedDirectoryTree properties'
        WHEN [DirID] > 0 AND  [DirsCount] > 0 THEN 'YES'
        WHEN [DirID] is null and [DirsCount] is null THEN 'NO'
        ELSE ' ' END

ALTER TABLE
    dbo.TEST_concat
ADD
    [Actions] AS
    CASE WHEN [protocol] = 'CIFS' AND [Error Messages] LIKE 'monitor type mismatch' AND [Scanned] = 'Yes' THEN 'Needs action'
         WHEN [protocol] = 'NFS' AND [DirsCount] = 0 AND [Scanned] = 'in Shares table, but not SortedDirectoryTree properties' THEN 'Needs action'
         WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE 'Pruned Different Security Type' or [Error Messages] LIKE 'mismatch' THEN 'Needs action'
         WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE 'access denied' THEN 'Needs action'
         WHEN [protocol] = 'CIFS' AND  [Scanned] = 'in Shares table, but not SortedDirectoryTree properties' THEN 'Needs action'
         WHEN  [Error Messages] LIKE 'the inherited' or [Error Messages] LIKE 'the path' or [Error Messages] LIKE 'missing inheritance' THEN 'Needs action'
         WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE 'Access is Denied. (1)'  AND [DirsCount] < 3 THEN 'Needs action'
         WHEN [protocol] = 'CIFS' AND [protocol] = 'NFS' THEN 'Needs action'
        ELSE ' ' END

ALTER TABLE
    dbo.TEST_concat
ADD
    [HowToFix] AS
    CASE WHEN [protocol] = 'CIFS' AND [Error Messages] LIKE 'monitor type mismatch' AND [Scanned] = 'Yes' THEN 'Backend problems. Security is not visible'
        WHEN [protocol] = 'NFS' AND [DirsCount] = 0 AND [Scanned] = 'in Shares table, but not SortedDirectoryTree properties' THEN 'Backend problems. Security is not visible'
        WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE 'Pruned Different Security Type' or [Error Messages] LIKE 'mismatch' THEN 'Change to NFS'
        WHEN [protocol] = 'CIFS' AND  [Scanned] = 'in Shares table, but not SortedDirectoryTree properties' THEN 'Backend problems. Security is not visible'
        WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE 'access denied' THEN 'Give permission to Varonis'
        WHEN [protocol] = 'CIFS' AND  [Scanned] = 'in Shares table, but not SortedDirectoryTree properties' THEN 'Backend problems. Security is not visible'
        WHEN  [Error Messages] LIKE 'the inherited' or [Error Messages] LIKE 'the path' or [Error Messages] LIKE 'missing inheritance' THEN 'Ignore Error'
        WHEN [Error Messages] LIKE 'Access is Denied. (1)'  AND [DirsCount] < 3 THEN 'Give permission to Varonis'
        ELSE ' ' END ' END
```

Answer (score 4):

Uhh ... You don't, but your workaround options are..

- Reproduce the computation of the first computed column when calculating the second one.
- Create a view that SELECTS your table plus first computed column, and create your second computed column based on the first.
- Create a stored procedure where the first computed column is in a subquery, the second one is in a main query, and return all rows in your main query.

btw looking at your T-SQL you may want to consider a lookup table with all of these actions/howtofix, and in queries you can JOIN on that lookup table and return the correct action.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you elaborate on the lookup table you recommend I create and then join? To my understanding, I would enter all the possible 'actions' in one column and then the possible 'how to fix' options in the next column. However, they are not intertwined. For instance, for every 'Needs Action' value in 'Actions', it may not always be the same 'how to fix' value. I've been working with MSSQL for two days now, I apologize if I'm not making sense!

Answer (score 2):

Use the full expression instead of `[Scanned]`. For example, instead of

```
ADD
    [Actions] AS
    CASE WHEN [protocol] = 'CIFS' AND [Error Messages] LIKE 'monitor type mismatch' AND [Scanned] = 'Yes' THEN 'Needs action'
```

code:

```
ADD
    [Actions] AS
    CASE WHEN [protocol] = 'CIFS' AND [Error Messages] LIKE 'monitor type mismatch' AND CASE WHEN [DirID] > 0 AND [DirsCount] is NULL THEN 'in Shares table, but not SortedDirectoryTree properties'
    WHEN [DirID] > 0 AND  [DirsCount] > 0 THEN 'YES'
    WHEN [DirID] is null and [DirsCount] is null THEN 'NO'
    ELSE ' ' END = 'Yes' THEN 'Needs action'
```

Hardly convenient, but that's SQL.